Create custom withStyle function
I am trying to create custom withStyle function, as you can see in the code snippet below I built this function to provide dynamic style for the given word according to specific conditions:
fun annotatedWord(word: String): AnnotatedString {
    return buildAnnotatedString {
        when {
            word.isDigitsOnly() -> {
                withStyle(
                    SpanStyle(
                        color = Color.Red,
                    )
                ) {
                    append(word)
                }
            }

            word.contains('@') -> {
                withStyle(
                    SpanStyle(
                        color = Color.Yellow,
                    )
                ) {
                    append(word)
                }
            }

            else -> {
                withStyle(
                    SpanStyle(
                        color = Color.Black,
                    )
                ) {
                    append(word)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

But When user enter sentence I want to split it into words and use annotatedWord function again:
fun annotatedSentence(sentence: String): AnnotatedString {
    return buildAnnotatedString {
        val words = sentence.split(" ")
        words.forEach { word ->
            when {
                word.isDigitsOnly() -> {
                    withStyle(
                        SpanStyle(
                            color = Color.Red,
                        )
                    ) {
                        append(word)
                    }
                }

                word.contains('@') -> {
                    withStyle(
                        SpanStyle(
                            color = Color.Yellow,
                        )
                    ) {
                        append(word)
                    }
                }

                else -> {
                    withStyle(
                        SpanStyle(
                            color = Color.Black,
                        )
                    ) {
                        append(word)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

How I can reuse annotatedWord function in annotatedSentence function instead of copy paste it?
I tried to write it like this:
fun annotatedWord(word: String): AnnotatedString {
    return when {
        word.isDigitsOnly() -> {
            buildAnnotatedString {
                withStyle(
                    SpanStyle(
                        color = Color.Red,
                    )
                ) {
                    append(word)
                }
            }
        }

        word.contains('@') -> {
            buildAnnotatedString {
                withStyle(
                    SpanStyle(
                        color = Color.Yellow,
                    )
                ) {
                    append(word)
                }
            }
        }

        else -> {
            buildAnnotatedString {
                withStyle(
                    SpanStyle(
                        color = Color.Black,
                    )
                ) {
                    append(word)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

But it did not work
